# Can the Server tell the Client to refresh the page?

Tags: client-server

I have a Client that tell my server to contact another server and save the data there upon saving if successful I can receive a callback, how can I then tell the Client to refresh the page because this 2nd Server is also sending data to the Client, can I do it using headers?

Comment: Since you mentioned `client` and `refresh`, I think you should clarify your targeting environment, in other words, your application is running in `browser` or not?

Comment: In browser Node.js server-side

Answer (score 4):

There is no tranditional ways to push messages (refresh request and so on) to the webpage directly from the server.

Before giving some solutions, I'm sorry to say that your description to your question is quite ambiguous. `server`, `another server`, `this 2nd Server is also sending data to the Client` does not make much sense. You may reorganize your description to show the whole business logic better. Giving necessary code will be better.

So focusing on **sending message from server to client within browser environment**, there are several ways you could consider:

### Ajax

You could use ajax to request the server at client side. You can poll the server at regular intervals, checking the response to determine whether the page should be refreshed.

**Pro:** widely supported, easy for both client side and server side

**Con:** polling is not a real-time solution and will make some redundant requests

### Websocket

**Pro:** real-time bidirectional socket-like communication

**Con:** may be too heavy for the simple task you mentioned

### Server push

Part of PWA specification

**Pro:** allow direct communication from server to client

**Con:** complexity, insufficient browser support